# Stop or mute FB video when closing modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, facebook

I have a bootstrap modal popup to show a facebook video, but when i close it, it keeps playing and i want it to stop or atleast mute when i close down the modal.

my code:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=667393203349368";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

    <div class="col-md-12" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-video-1">
    <a href="" onclick="return false;" >
        <div class="test-video-title">
        <h3>Test 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="test-video-content">
        <img src="Images/partnerji/default.png" alt="VideolistImg"  />
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>


    <div class="modal fade" id="test-video-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-v-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
              <h3 class="modal-title">Test 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-v-body">
                <div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" data-width="800" data-show-text="true">&#160;</div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `hidden.bs.modal event` from bootstrap. Here is a code sample I found on a related SO answer.

```
 $(function(){
$('#test-video-1').modal({
    show: false
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).find('.fb-video')[0].pause();
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the video is still playing after this. I tryed solutions from many posts but no luck

Comment: I tried replicating your situation on codepen but the video does not appear So there's little I can do.

Comment: Try another random video from fb, i took the one from dev api example, that one bugs sometimes

Comment: Tried that on codepen and jsbin but still wouldn't show the video. Perhaps I need a key from facebook to be able to view the video. I will check

Answer (score 0):

The `.fb-video` element gets replaced by an iframe; you have no access to that from your scripts because of the Same Origin Policy.

But they have an API that you can use to control the player - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api